# Pointer to pointer dereference with pre-increment operator

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, pre-increment

The following program gives output as 17,29,45; I can't understand what does `**++pp;` mean. Can anyone explain the program in detail.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        static int a[] = {10, 22, 17, 29, 45};
        static int *p[] = {a, a + 2, a + 1, a + 4, a + 3};
        int **pp = p;
        **++pp;
        printf("%d %d %d", **pp, *pp[3], pp[0][2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `**++pp;` is the same as `* (* ( ++pp));`. It first increments the pointer, then deferences twice (*the first dereference result is of pointer type, to be elaborate*).

However, the value obtained by dereferencing is not used. If you have compiler warnings enabled, you'll get to see something like

> warning: value computed is not used

You can remove the dereferencing, it's no use.

Comment: output is affected when i comment out this statement

Comment: @NikhilVerma I'm not asking to comment out the statement, remove the dereferences, use `++pp;` and you'll get the same result.

Comment: Of course it is affected, as `pp` is not incremented, if you comment it out.